# Mutating Values within a List

Tags: r, list, dplyr

I have the following example code

```
library(survival)
fit2 <- coxph( Surv(stop, event) ~ size, data = bladder )
# single curve
ggadjustedcurves(fit2, data = bladder)

fit2 <- coxph( Surv(stop, event) ~ size + strata(rx), data = bladder )
# average in groups
ggadjustedcurves(fit2, data = bladder, method = "average", variable = "rx")

a<-ggadjustedcurves(fit2, data = bladder, method = "average", variable = "rx")
```

This is just a technical plot from a statistical model that plots a "survival curve". You can plot it and see for yourself. I am trying to change the values of the "curves" themselves however. In the object a there contains a list called "surv" (under both data and plot_env). This is where the y-coordinates are coming from (from either one, I am not sure).

I would like to instead perform a simple transformation (1-surv). That is, the beginning value of "1" would be changed to 0 and so forth. This will achieve the effect of having the survival lines go "up" instead of "down". Just an interpretation thing.

How can I achieve this effect? Essentially, what I want to do is go into the list and do "1-surv". There are 76 elements in the list so 38 y-coordinates for variable 1 and 38 for variable 2. I have a weak grasp of programming but I'm sure what I'm asking is easily doable.

Again, to describe my problem, I would like to change the y-coordinates (presumably contained under data or plot_env under the list surv) to *mutate* them.

Thanks for all your help!

**EDIT**

I attempted the following:

```
b<-a$data$surv
a$data$surv<- 1-b
b
```

This gives me the intended solution. is there  a more elegant solution to this? perhaps using dplyr etc.? I realize this is a simple task but would like any pointers on where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is more elegant but it is more tidy.

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)

complement <- function(g){
  g$data$surv <- 1 - g$data$surv
  g
}

fit2 <- coxph( Surv(stop, event) ~ size + strata(rx), data = bladder )
# average in groups
a <- ggadjustedcurves(fit2, data = bladder, method = "average", variable = "rx")

complement(a)
```

Note that the object `a` was not changed, to do so the function's result will have to be assigned back to it. Or keep the object as it was output by `ggadjustedcurves` and assign to another object.

```
b <- complement(a)
```

Comment: Excellent. Exactly what I was looking for. I don't need to change object `a` in the first place so this solution is tidy.